# Connecting SSH server through chrome (or any browser)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

My end goal is to display an index.html (on a browser) which is at the ssh server.

I'm a newbie in networking. I'm able to successfully connect the server to the terminal using the command `ssh -x serverName@ip-address`. But when I type `ip-address:20` or `ip-address` in the url bar of the chrome,I'm getting "Site cannot be reached" message. 
My first question is, can I "connect" an ssh server through chrome.
If yes, how to do it? 
("Connect" in the sense, I've to display an index.html)

System Configuration:

- ssh server OS: ubuntu 16.04
- Local Machine OS: ubuntu 18.04
- Both the local and and the ssh server are on the same network

(Sorry for my English)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

The same *machine* could of course serve SSH and HTTP at the same time, but you would need to install a separate HTTP service on it (Apache, Nginx, etc.) and it would run on a different port than that of SSH.

SSH is a completely different protocol from HTTP. The server's SSH service **will not be able** to understand the browser's HTTP requests, nor provide HTTP responses that the browser would understand.

So you will not get any results by telling a browser to connect to an SSH port. (The port number for SSH is 22, by the way – not 20.) Some browsers will even refuse this outright, but others will try anyway and will merely receive a "Protocol mismatch" message.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you think of a webbased ssh terminal? Examples could be **Gate One**
Check out http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and just found a solution.

https://github.com/sspreitzer/docker-shellinabox

$ docker run -p 4200:4200 -e SIAB_PASSWORD=xyz678abc -e SIAB_SUDO=true sspreitzer/shellinabox:latest

(Default user "guest"... password "xyz678abc")

Then you can use that docker shell to access other machines

hope this help!

[shellinabox docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mogJC.png)

Comment: I am really not clear that this is an answer to the question. Could you please clarify what this solution will achieve?

Comment: lol sure. I think more like the original question is confusing. "Can I "connect" an ssh server through chrome. If yes, how to do it? ("Connect" in the sense, I've to display an index.html)"

Comment: My answer is towards the first part under common understanding . "Can I "connect" an ssh server through chrome.". the answer is yes. you totally can with shellinabox. and using docker version will just save everyone a little bit time

Comment: the confusing part is the second part -- "Connect" in the sense, I've to display an index.html". the original question doesn't mention how he/she want to "display the index.html". if I ssh into this machine and "cat index.html" does it display it?

Comment: or if I trying understand his intension since he is using "-x" for ssh already. He/she is probably asking why X11 forwarding is not working. lol

Comment: if that is the case, then changing sshd config to allow X11 forwarding and just type 'firefox' after login through ssh. that should pop out a remote browser and according to it's Nginx or Apache config he will be able to access the index.html probably through http://localhost:80

Comment: Or even easier, why not just fix the original http server. that is just a http server config question or probably Iptable or apparmor problem to expose 80 or 443

Comment: if we check the originally question more throughly. why " ip-address:20"? port 20 is neither ssh nor http/s. once again I think the question is confusing but the intension for StackExchange is to serve people coming for the topic of the question. and I hope my answer will help that part of the audience.